# React-Redux: State updated but not copied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, reducers

In my reducer I can't understund why my state returns updated but not copied.

```
const loginReducer = (state = {}, action) => {

    let newstate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))
    const { type, payload } = action

    switch(type) {
        case constant.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            //
            newstate = { login: [{ user: payload.user, password: payload.password, logged: true }] }
            console.log(newstate.login)
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return newstate

}
```

Surely it's a simple thing what I'm missing, but I can't figure out it

Comment: Why do you feel you need to clone with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are completely re-assigning `newstate` in this line:

```
newstate = { login: [{ user: payload.user, password: payload.password, logged: true }] }
```

If you want to maintain the current values in `state` you need to also include them:

```
newstate = { ...newstate, login: [{ user: payload.user, password: payload.password, logged: true }] }
```

The above uses object spread, which you may or may not have in your babel configuration.  You can also use `Object.assign` to achieve the same thing:

```
newstate = Object.assign(newstate, { login: [{ user: payload.user, password: payload.password, logged: true }] });
```

Comment: Hi Davin, I did as you suggested but I've recived this error: aught Error: Cannot find module "./src/reducers/loginReducer"

Comment: Do you have object spread in your babel configuration?  I'll edit another method to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I have installed babel-preset-stage-2 but currently I have the same problem

Comment: I have tried also with Object.assign but it doesn't copy my state anyway, damn I can't understund what's wrong